# What is an efficient way to move in a specific direction relative to its data?

Tags: c++, if-statement

So I'm working on a mini-game where you are a player in an arena with monsters. The goal is to kill all the monsters by shooting them. You can move up/right/down/left, and so can the monsters. If the monsters touch you, you die.

I have to create a player AI for the player to try to stay alive.

So I have defined an integer for each "Danger Zone" for each direction (DangerUp/DangerDown/DangerRight/DangerLeft) and initialized them all to zero. So it looks like this:

```
int DangerUp = 0, DangerDown = 0, DangerRight = 0, DangerLeft = 0;
```

If there is a monster above of me, dangerUp will increment by one. If there is one below me, dangerDown will increment by one. Same with the other two.

So what I'm trying to write (in psuedeocode) is essentially:

if I'm surrounded by three (which means 3 of the 4 Danger variables have a value of 1), move to the direction where the danger is 0.

I was planning on doing this:

```
if (DangerUP == 1 && DangerDOWN == 1 && DangerLEFT == 1 && DangerRIGHT == 0) // if surrounded by 3 in the up, down, left direction

{
// move right;
player_x_direction++; // (this moves my character one direction to the right)

}
```

and then I plan on doing three else if's where I test for all combinations of having 3 of the 4 variables equal to 1.

Is there a simpler way to do this where I can just move in the direction of whatever danger direction  is = 0?

Comment: Just pointing out a code smell: the functionality of `player_x_direction++;` should be extracted into it own method. Perhaps the method will only execute that one line, but it'll make it easy to add more logic in the future (collision detection, for example), without having to hunt down every instance where the player is moved.

Comment: Do you have your heart set on having distinct variables indicating danger in each direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the danger values are always 0 or 1, then:

```
int danger_everywhere = (dangerUp << 3) | (dangerDown << 2)
                      | (dangerLeft << 1) | (dangerRight);
```

Then:

```
if (danger_everywhere == 8 + 4 + 2)
     move_right();

if (danger_everywhere == 8 + 4 + 1)
     move_left();

if (danger_everywhere == 8 + 2 + 1)
     move_down();

if (danger_everywhere == 4 + 2 + 1)
     move_up();
```